# Outlook attachments.add not working when using WordEditor in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Excel file which has an embeded word object for editing the e-mail message and then sending it.

In the code, problem is right after i set the WordEditor object to paste the message, any added attachment previously added is missed, and if i change the code do add it after WordEditor processes the message, nothing is attached although no error is shown.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Editor As Object
    Dim ObjMail as Outlook.Mailitem
    Dim WdTag As OLEObject
    Dim WdDocTag As Word.Document
    Dim WSmail as Worksheet

    set WSmail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")

    Set WdTag = WSmail.OLEObjects("WordTags")
    WdTag.Verb xlVerbPrimary
    Set WdDocTag = WdTag.Object
    WdDocTag.Content.Copy

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With ObjMail
       .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\txt.txt",,1

       'If I check the Attachments Property of ObjMail here at runtime,
       'I can see the information on the attached file. 
       'However, as soon as the code continues, it vanishes.     

       .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
       Set Editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
       Editor.Content.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False

      .To = "Someone"
      .Cc = "Someone"
      .Subject = "MySubject"
      .Display
   End with
```

EDIT:

Actually I found that after setting `.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText`, any attachments set after or before that line will be placed in the message body.

Now the question would be, how to show the attachment in its proper field and not in the message body?

Comment: SOmething not logical to me: Your Editor object is part of your email object(`Set Editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor`) and you are pasting from it. From your description, the Editor should be derived from an object in your Excel file

Comment: No, man. I'm pasting in it, from the Word OLE object, from which i copy previously `WdDocTag.Content.Copy` and later, after Editor is Set, `Editor.Content.Paste`.

Comment: A debugging step I would take would be to move `.Display` much higher and step through the code, check at which point the attachment appears, and disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the below code:

```
 Set oOutlookMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)    'Start a new e-mail
    With oOutlookMail
        .Display    'Had to move this command here to resolve a bug only existent in Access 2016!

        'To Recipient(s)
        Set oOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(sTo)
        oOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

        'CC Recipient(s)
        If Not IsMissing(sCC) Then
            Set oOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(sCC)
            oOutlookRecip.Type = olCC
        End If

        'BCC Recipient(s)
        If Not IsMissing(sBCC) Then
            Set oOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(sBCC)
            oOutlookRecip.Type = olBCC
        End If

        .Subject = sSubject    'Subject
        Set oOutlookInsp = .GetInspector    'Retains the signature if applicable
        .Importance = 1    'Importance Level  0=Low,1=Normal,2=High

        '        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        Set oWordEditor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        'oWordEditor.Content.Paste    'Overwrite any existing content, ie:signature
        oWordEditor.Application.Selection.Start = 0
        oWordEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

        ' Add attachments to the message.
        If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
            If IsArray(AttachmentPath) Then
                For i = LBound(AttachmentPath) To UBound(AttachmentPath)
                    If AttachmentPath(i) <> "" And AttachmentPath(i) <> "False" Then
                        Set oOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath(i))
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                If AttachmentPath <> "" And AttachmentPath(i) <> "False" Then
                    Set oOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        For Each oOutlookRecip In .Recipients
            If Not oOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
                bProbRecip = True
                'Display msg to user?
            End If
        Next

        If bProbRecip = False And bEdit = False Then  'Send the e-mail
            .Send
        End If
    End With
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[MS Access – Use Word Document As Outlook E-mail Body](https://www.devhut.net/2018/04/04/ms-access-use-word-document-as-outlook-e-mail-body/)